# What is the exception for no string being entered and does it get presented?

Tags: c#

I've been given a task to create an application involving data string entry, which works fine, but when it comes to surrounding it in a try...catch, no matter what exception is placed, the try is always accepted regardless of what is entered. I need the correct exception to display when nothing has been typed in.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a name:");

            Console.WriteLine();

            string a = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Product myProduct = new Product();
            myProduct.getName(a);

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your name is now: {0}", myProduct.getName(a));
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (a == "")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Product
    {
        private string Name { get; set; }

        public string getName(string o)
        {
            return o.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have some kind of fundamental misunderstanding of how exceptions work. You should probably go back and read up on them a bit more.

Comment: What do you mean by "the try is always accepted"? What exception would you *expect* to be thrown, and where? You're calling `ToString()` on a non-null string reference... how could that be exceptional?

Comment: You should also read up on the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). It'll also help you eliminate the need for try/catch blocks.

Comment: One of your main problems is that the empty string is not a null string. You need to check for the empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in that `try` block *would* throw an exception.  All it's doing is writing output to the console.

The "exceptional" case you're looking for is when the *input* fails some custom validation (in this case, is an empty string).  The *input* is gathered before that `try` block.  And since this is custom business logic, it's up to that business logic to *throw* the exception.  Something like this:

```
try
{
    string a = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
        throw new Exception("Value must not be empty.");
    // the rest of the code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

***However***, this isn't really a good practice either.  This is using exceptions for *logic flow* which isn't their intended purpose.  There are cases where validation logic can throw exceptions, but I wouldn't consider this one of them.  This sounds more like the job of an `if` statement:

```
string a = Console.ReadLine();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
    Console.WriteLine("Value must not be empty.");
else
{
    // the rest of the code
}
```

As an aside, a usual tell-tale sign that exceptions are being incorrectly used for logic flow is when the *details* of the exception aren't of any importance.  Note in the code you posted that the only thing being read from the `Exception` object is its message.  In my working example, that message is explicitly defined.  If a custom message is defined and that custom message is all that's needed from the exception, then an exception isn't really what should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You won't ever throw an exception in the way that you want, I would suspect.

Instead of a try...catch loop, why not just check if the string is empty before you write it:

```
if (a == "")
    {
         Console.WriteLine("You must enter a value etc");
    }
else{
    Console.WriteLine("Your name is now: {0}", myProduct.getName(a));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The general rule of thumb for exceptions is that you should only be checking for them if its REALLY unexpected to happen, but you can't guarantee it'll never happen. If something is going to be a common occurrence, just make it part of the logic.

Comment: `"if its REALLY unexpected to happen, but you can't guarantee it'll never happen"` - I like how you worded that explanation *a lot* more than my usual "only for 'exceptional' cases" wording.  Thanks!

Comment: Heh heh, nice to hear. Thanks for the compliment. :)